# Error connecting controller Error: Cannot update an unmounted root. at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (r

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony

An error occurs when I try to perform a simple rendering of a React component in my Twig view using react-ux.I am using symfony 6

Twig view :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}test react{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container" id="root">
        <div {{ react_component('SearchBar', { 'fullName': 'Robert' }) }}></div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

react component :

```
import React from 'react';
export default function (props) {
    return <div>Hello {props.fullName} test de mon app</div>;
}
```

app.js :

```
import './bootstrap';


import { registerReactControllerComponents } from '@symfony/ux-react';
registerReactControllerComponents(require.context('./react/controllers', true, /\.(j|t)sx?$/));
```